# the system cannot find the path specified error on Crystal Reports ExportToDisk

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal reports in my WPF application to generate reports, getting below error

> "the system cannot find the path specified error" on ExportToDisk.

```
irptDocument = new ReportDocument();
rptDocument.InitReport += new EventHandler(this.OnReportDocInit);
irptDocument.Load(astrReportName);
irptDocument.SetDataSource(adtbResult);
irptDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,lstrReportFullName);
```

Path where to save as pdf is a valid path, still I am getting above error.

Answer (score 0):

This is very common error while we something missing or not set (even for runtime). If you getting error in win7, then also check second link.

While searching answers of your question, someone resolved this error by

> I found out the problem; the auto-generated file name seems to have
>   been too long for the app-server. I changes the name of the class to
>   PCWS and it worked fine. It's a shame Sun One Studio (which creates
>   these massive file names doesn't warn you

Please check this links :

https://scn.sap.com/thread/3689925

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-update/the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-error/dae5f759-b053-4a4a-87af-42e79f517631?auth=1